# Marketing Cloud Abandoned Cart data to use in Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I finished product catalogue tracking, connected ready-made data extensions from Predictive Intelligence (IGO Digital). Most of IGO_ data extensions are flowing back from IGO to MC data extensions. But according to this article:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319381&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

- PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS
- PI_ABANDONED_CART_EVENT

above data extensions will be empty. I know that to make this DE data flow we need to integrate it using some Salesforce assistance.

**The question is:** Is there any way to integrate data from cart abandonments without paid services from Marketing Cloud Professional Services? https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/06/abandoned-cart-technical.html

Any API so we can access the data and integrate using custom package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there are no abandoned cart/browse items available - not even for retrieval via API - as certain parameters need to be defined (which currently can only be done by Salesforce Professional Services).

These parameters are necessary to define when a cart is considered abandoned and include the following:

- Timing for cart/browse abandonment (eg. 1 hour / 1 day)
- Lockout Time (Frequency Capping; when are consecutive abandonments counted)

Further parameters that are requested by Salesforce Professional Services are needed for the cart/browse abandonment CSV file uploads to the enhanced FTP (currently regarded as best practice implementation and described in the solution kits provided by Salesforce):

- Maximum number of articles by session
- Which products should be considered (for example most expensive in the cart; longest or most often viewed)
- Attributes per product to include in the CSV (for example the unique product id, product name, etc.)
- Attributes per profile (for example the email address provided via collect code)

Comment: Thanks Markus. I will contact them then for quote. Do you know how much time do they normally need to complete the simple 1 day abandonment requirement?